# Parse ISO date by Period in Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, jodatime, java-time

i want to replace `JodaTime` by `Java 8 DateTime API`.

I've got `ISO-8601` period described = `P2W5DT11H8M`

In `JodaTime` i parse it very simply by executing the following code:

`Period.parse("P2W5DT11H8M")` and i get the successful `Period` object.

Can i do the same in Java 8?

Comment: And what is your intention regarding the result? Do you plan to add the period to a `LocalDateTime`? If so then the addition algorithm implicitly suggested by the answer of Assylias (separate additions in two steps) is not exactly what Joda-Time defines and might yield different results in some edge cases. Furthermore, there are no formatting capabilities in Java-8 for periods/durations so you might think again about your decision.

Comment: @MenoHochschild i want to have the same Period as it was in JodaTime. Currently, i see that i'm losing the data, for example i'm not able to operate minutes, instead of it i should use extra implementation from Java 8 - the Duration class.

Answer (score 5):

A Period in Java 8 only has year/month/day components. A Duration has hour/minute/second components. It seems that you will need to parse the string manually. One option could look like the code below (you need to add input validation etc.) - there may be better alternatives.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(PeriodAndDuration.parse("P2W5DT11H8M"));
}

public static class PeriodAndDuration {
  private final Period p;
  private final Duration d;

  public PeriodAndDuration(Period p, Duration d) {
    this.p = p;
    this.d = d;
  }

  public Period getPeriod() {
    return p;
  }

  public Duration getDuration() {
    return d;
  }

  public static PeriodAndDuration parse(String input) {
    int periodStart = input.indexOf("P");
    int timeStart = input.indexOf("T");
    Period p = Period.parse(input.substring(periodStart, timeStart));
    Duration d = Duration.parse("P" + input.substring(timeStart, input.length()));
    return new PeriodAndDuration(p, d);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return p.toString() + d.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, as far as i understand, parsing such full string i should be responsible and think that i can parse only year/month/day from it.

Comment: As far as I know yes - somebody else may come up with a better answer.

Comment: This kind of combination has already been written in [`org.threeten.extra.PeriodDuration`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html). See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50809751/642706) for details.

Answer (score 0):

## `PeriodDuration`

> Period.parse("P2W5DT11H8M")
>
> Can i do the same in Java 8?

Yes.

```
org.threeten.extra.PeriodDuration.parse( "P2W5DT11H8M" )
```

## *ThreeTen-Extra* project

The *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later are supplemented by the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. This project is run by the same man as who ran Joda-Time and JSR 310 (the spec for *java.time*), [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen).

That project offers the [`PeriodDuration`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html) that combines the ideas of the `Period` and `Duration` classes in *java.time*.

Documentation for [`PeriodDuration.parse`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) says:

> Obtains an instance from a text string such as PnYnMnDTnHnMnS.

```
PeriodDuration pd = PeriodDuration.parse( "P2W5DT11H8M" ) ;
```

## Caveat

Think twice before using `PeriodDuration`.

The two concepts of years-months-days and hours-minutes-seconds were separated in *java.time* for a reason. If you give it a ponder, you may find that it may not make sense to combine the two in practice.

If you do proceed with this class, be sure to study the documentation and its behavior. Practice with some scenarios to see if it meets your expectations and needs.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -4):

Short answer:

```
Period period = Period.parse("P2W5DT11H8M");
```

Long answer: There is a good description by Oracle on [when to use Period or Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html). It comes with some nice code-samples, and should answer any follow-up questions you might have.

Comment: That will throw an exception at runtime.