# How to convert time in a string to an integer in Java?

Tags: java, json, int

I am getting a JSON response with value of time like this from Amazon:

```
"Duration": 
{
    "name": "Duration",
    "value": "PT7H"
}
```

That stands for 7 hours. If the input is 5 minutes then it will be like this:

```
"Duration": 
{
    "name": "Duration",
    "value": "PT5M"
}
```

How can I convert the PT5M to time in seconds?  So, if the string is "PT5M" (which is 300 seconds) then I want it to be `300` as the output.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably needs more comparable input and output, but it's a basic substringing and comparing the (two) end "string variables".

Comment: You may use 3rd-party-libraries like Joda-Time.

Comment: I've heard it said that even the creators of Joda Time now recommend the Java 8 date and time API. Avoid depending on a 3rd party library for this. @newuserua_ext

Comment: Thanks @OleV.V. . After this question i read about JSR 310.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those time durations are in standard [ISO 8601 format](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/ISO_8601). You can use the [Java 8 date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Use the [Duration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class' parse method. Then convert to other Chrono units. (Code deliberately not provided, so you can learn how to do this.)

Answer (score 2):

[Java 8 Duration class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-)

I think this is what you are looking for. Just use the parse method. It takes the same format that you are getting. And parsing of Json you can do with Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

I can thik in a parsing  function like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
 throws IOException, ParseException {

 String corvertme = "PT7H5M";

 Date extractedDate  = parseAmazonDate(corvertme);

 System.out.println(extractedDate);


 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.setTime(extractedDate);
 long daySeconds = (c.get(Calendar.SECOND) +
                    c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 60 +
                    c.get(Calendar.HOUR) * 3600);
 System.out.println(daySeconds);

 }

  private static Date parseAmazonDate(String corvertme) throws ParseException {

char[] hourCharacters = corvertme.replaceAll("[PT]", "").toCharArray();

 String[] hourArray =  "00:00:00".split(":");

 int HOUR_INDEX=0;
 int MIN_INDEX=1;
 int SEG_INDEX=2;

 char timeValue = 0;
 char posValue =  0;

 for(int i = 0; i < hourCharacters.length; i++){
     timeValue = hourCharacters[i];
     if(hourCharacters.length > i + 1){
         posValue = hourCharacters[++i];
     }

      switch (posValue) {
        case 'H':
                hourArray[HOUR_INDEX] = String.valueOf(timeValue);
                break;
        case 'M':
               hourArray[MIN_INDEX] = String.valueOf(timeValue);
                break;
        case 'S':
                hourArray[SEG_INDEX] = String.valueOf(timeValue);
        default:
            break;
        }   

 }


 String stringDate = hourArray[HOUR_INDEX] + ":"+hourArray[MIN_INDEX] + ":" + hourArray[SEG_INDEX];

 return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(stringDate);
```

}

Hope Help you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the effort. + 1 for that. But using the Duration class in Java 8 us much easier. :)

Comment: This Answer uses troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score -1):

This question is similar to [Parse ISO Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427681/parse-iso-date-by-period-in-java-8).

Just find out the last index of M, H and S. Find the values of minute. hour and  second by parsing the string to int. And then calculate time.